# Flipping with navigation keys divs that are :checked in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the **next** & **previous** buttons to navigate through the divs that was selected in checkboxes. That means that user selects several options press the **start** button and do some actions in first selected option, then he press **next** and navigates to next div and again do some actions.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#roomsubmit').click(function () {
        $(".room").hide();
        if ($("#node").is(':checked')) {
            $("#hallway").show();
            $("#hallway").addClass("roomNew");
        } else if ($("#node-2").is(':checked')) {
            $("#livingroom").show();
            $("#livingroom").addClass("roomNew");
        } else if ($("#node-3").is(':checked')) {
            $("#bedroom").show();
            $("#bedroom").addClass("roomNew");
        } else if ($("#node-4").is(':checked')) {
            $("#playroom").show();
            $("#playroom").addClass("roomNew");
        } 
    });


    $(function () {
        $(".swap").on({
            click: function () {
                var parent = $(this).closest('.roomNew');
                parent.css('display', 'none');
                if (this.id == 'previousBtn') {
                    parent.prev('.roomNew').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    parent.next('.roomNew').css('display', 'block');
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.room {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="node">Hallway
    <input type="checkbox" id="node" />
</label>
<label for="node-2">Livingroom
    <input type="checkbox" id="node-2" />
</label>
<label for="node-3">Bedroom
    <input type="checkbox" id="node-3" />
</label>
<label for="node-4">Playroom
    <input type="checkbox" id="node-4" />
</label>

<button id="roomsubmit">Start calculation</button>

<div id="hallway" class="room">Works in hallway
    <button class="swap previousBtn" id="previousBtn">prev</button>
    <button class="swap nextBtn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
</div>
<div id="livingroom" class="room">Works in livingroom
    <button class="swap previousBtn" id="previousBtn">prev</button>
    <button class="swap nextBtn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
</div>
<div id="bedroom" class="room">Works in bedrrom
    <button class="swap previousBtn" id="previousBtn">prev</button>
    <button class="swap nextBtn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
</div>
<div id="playroom" class="room">Works in playroom
    <button class="swap previousBtn" id="previousBtn">prev</button>
    <button class="swap nextBtn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/nikitaastakhov/2gos4r4a/182/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something for you, Roby. Sorry for delay - had to work it out.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gos4r4a/184/)</kbd>

First, there are now two arrays: arrRooms (an array of objects which map the nodename to the room), and newRooms (an array to store checkmarked rooms - poor name, but oh well).

The arrRooms array is used to get the room name when given the node. This eliminated all those if-else lines.

A new function `$('input:checkbox').click` was created to add/remove the checked/unchecked nodes from the `newRooms` array. This leaves you with an array containing just the checked rooms.

Next, the `#roomsubmit.click` function was simplified to use the above arrays. All it does now is (1) grab the first item in the newRooms array (the checked rooms) (2) display that room's DIV, and (3) remove that item from the newRooms array. This creates a "cafeteria plate" scenario where each time you click #roomsubmit ("Start Calculation" button), the next checked room is displayed.

**Important:** Note that you have several elements with the same ID (`id="nextBtn"` and `id="previousBtn"`). Not allowed, I'm afraid. Every ID must be completely unique in the DOM. However, there is no need to use IDs at all since they are not referenced in the code at the moment. The jQuery selector uses the class, so just delete the ID attributes from the HTML.

By the way, to make the `previous` button work, you can modify your swap function to work with the above, or else change your approach completely and just create another empty array and when you delete a room from the `newRooms[]` array, add it into the `prevRooms[]` array. When the `previous` button is clicked, grab the room-to-display from the `prevRooms[]` array, delete it from there, and stick it back into the `newRooms[]` array. You will work it out... (In fact, you may need three variables: prevRooms array, currRoom var, and newRooms array --- put some legos on a desk to represent the checked rooms, and use three circles to represent the three arrays - and imagine clicking the next/prev buttons and moving the curr room lego from one pile into the next, and you'll quickly work out how to do this.)

**javascript/jQuery code:**

```
var tmp;
var arrRooms={'node':'hallway','node-2':'livingroom','node-3':'bedroom','node-4':'playroom','node-5':'cabinet','node-6':'kitchen','node-7':'bathroom','node-8':'wc'};
var newRooms=[];

$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        newRooms.push(this.id);
        //alert( JSON.stringify(newRooms) );
    }else{
        newRooms.splice(newRooms.indexOf(this.id),1); //delete from newRooms
        //alert( JSON.stringify(newRooms) );
    }
});

$('#roomsubmit').click(function () {
    $(".room").hide();
    tmp = arrRooms[newRooms[0]];
    //alert('tmp = ' +tmp);
    $('#' +tmp).addClass('roomNew').show();
    newRooms.splice(0,1);
    //alert( JSON.stringify(newRooms) );
});

$('.nextBtn').click(function(){
    $('#roomsubmit').click();
});


$(function () {
    $(".swap").on({
        click: function () {
            var parent = $(this).closest('.roomNew');
            parent.css('display', 'none');
            if (this.id == 'previousBtn') {
                parent.prev('.roomNew').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                parent.next('.roomNew').css('display', 'block');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's perfect. I'll try to make prev button work.